# False discovery rate of Benjamini Hochberg at level $\alpha$ under global null

Tags: false-discovery-rate

Suppose that we have null hypotheses $H_1, \cdots, H_n$. What is the FDR rate from Benjamini-Hochberg at level $\alpha$ the under the global null i.e. the assumption that the null hypotheses are all true. According to a book I am reading, it is $\alpha$, but I do not see why this is true. The FDR rate is defined to be $E[\frac{V}{R}]$, where $R$ is the number of rejected hypotheses, and $V$ is the number of rejected hypotheses that are true. Hence, $\frac{V}{R} = 1$ under the global null unless $V = 0$, and the probability that $V = 0$ appears to be much smaller than $1 - \alpha$, which would give us the FDR of $\alpha$.

Comment: Whether or not a procedure yields $P(V=0)\geq1-\alpha$ will depend on the particular procedure that is used. Suppose you test each individual hypothesis $H_i$ at individual level $\alpha=0$ (i.e., you never reject, no matter what the data says). Then, surely, $P(V=0)=1$ under the global null.